# Surfacing a large C++ library in .net-core

Tags: c#, c++, linux, .net-core

I have a large C++ library (1000's of objects) that I'd like to be able to access in C# on Linux.

Some background:

- The code has 1000's of objects
- The objects are often passed in as parameters, sometimes by reference and sometimes by a pointer
- The code is compiled native on Linux. It is open source so I can adjust how it is built if I like, though I can't alter the C++ code.
- I need to replicate the object code in C#
- I've done this once on windows: I can parse and write out .cpp files that are wrappers and use the c++/cli for doing the interop. This works.

There is no reason I can't do the same process to build .netcore interop files on the Linux side. I just have no idea how to go about doing it. I've read that PInvoke is supported. Is that my only option? Turn every method call, etc., into a C-like method call?

At the moment I do not need to do the same on Windows - just on the Linux side. So any solution that is Linux only is acceptable. I've already got a Windows-only solution using .net standard.

Comment: I know nothing about doing this with Core and Linux. But, on the normal Framework and Windows, you have two choices, either wrapping you C++ library in one or more COM classes and using COM interop, or by exporting a series of C-like functions (no this pointer, no name mangling) and calling them via P/Invoke. Get a copy of Adam Nathan's ".NET & COM" book to figure out your options. Now, having said that, I've never played with C++/CLI.

Comment: Thanks! On standard .NET you can actually expose full C++ objects without having to use PInvoke or COM by using the C++/CLI language that is still supported. Actually makes it very easy as long as you have some machinery to write the C++ wrapper classes. I have not tried the COM method. Perhaps that is foster?

Comment: Probably not. COM is an "interesting" object interface, but it adds a lot of quirks with threading models, apartments, etc. It was pretty cool in the 1990s, but it's different enough from the Framework that there are some disconnects in the interim layer.